# Why was I wrong choosing "Looks OK" for this triage review for a question about PHP and XSS?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, triage, review-suspension

I am quite confused about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27091217

The original question was terse but clear. The poster even gave two potential solutions and their downsides, and asked if there was another way to solve the issue. As far as I am concerned, this question looked OK. Another reviewer thought it looked OK too. Two reviewers thought it was unsalvageable. Eventually, the question was closed because it was not "focused" enough, and the poster was asked to "update the question so it focuses on one problem only".

First, I feel bad for the original poster, because I have no idea how their question could have been made more focused than it was. Should they have refrained from posting potential solutions? Also, four comments were posted and none of them seemed to imply a lack of focus of the original question.

Second, I got a 15-day ban from reviews because of my vote "Looks OK" on this question. What is that suspension supposed to achieve? Note that I had already been suspended before, because I had misunderstood what "Requires editing" meant. That previous suspension was fine with me, because it made me realize how wrong I indeed was (though the text around "Requires editing" should definitely be made clearer). But here, I have no idea how I am supposed to improve.

Comment: Your previous review suspension (8 days) begun on Aug 16, for ([triage/26941096](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26941096), [triage/26940324](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26940324), [triage/26940276](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26940276), [triage/26940811](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26940811), etc.). Each subsequent review suspension within X days of a previous one doubles the duration.

Comment: "An answer to this question would to write a complete sanitization library". That seems like a perfectly fine answer to me. And if the question admits a fine answer, the question seems fine too. For example, if someone were to google this question, shouldn't this be the answer they get?

Comment: My friend, when the answer requires you to write something the size of a novel, and then document and explain it, the question is too broad. When the answer is more than a few pages, the question is probably too broad.

Comment: If we took that approach we could get a robot to answer "you could solve your problem by writing a computer program" to most of the questions here and all move on to some other site. Such an answer really isn't sufficiently specific or detailed enough to be useful.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I did not say that the answer should explain how to write a sanitization library. I said that the answer would have been " a fullblown sanitization library is needed for this task, so there is no way around htmlpurifier".

Comment: Handy reading: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Comment: If you have access to this statistics about my account, you will notice that I have absolutely no shame in using "skip".

Comment: If the answer is "write sanitization library" then that should be posted as comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is too broad as scoped. An answer to this question would need to write a complete sanitization library, e.g. the "html purifier" which was already mentioned in question and comments.

Expecting an answer like that is not a reasonable answer for the scope of the site. I don't know how familiarized you are with the amount of work required to produce a library like this. To give you an idea, in case you are not aware of what would amount, the compressed "lite" (e.g. library only, no docs or tests) distribution of html purifier weights at 474Kb.

There is no sensible answer that can produced within the constraints of the platform. It's simply not practical or useful.

And if the expected answer is "you would need to code it yourself, there is no single magic PHP function that will do this work for you", then it's simply not useful for anyone.

Someone who wants an answer to a question like this should simply do a lot more research on preventing XSS injection with PHP. There are quite a few Q&As available on SO about that as well.

Comment: The alternative answer is "Just use HTML Purifier." An equally unsatisfying answer best left as it was: a comment.

Comment: The question says "without using _'html purifier' or smth [sic] else"_ (which I interpret as "any other third party library")

Comment: Understood and agreed, but sometimes the correct answer is "Don't be an idiot. You have a hammer. Use it to hit the nail."

Comment: "And if the expected answer is "you would need to code it yourself, there is no single magic PHP function that will do this work for you", then it's simply not useful for anyone." I don't really see why this is not helpful. It's a negative answer but one can learn also a lot from negative answers. Basically the question would then be why it's so difficult that a whole library is needed and not just a few lines of code.